# gaussian integers quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ denote the factor ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+3i)$. Show that $i-3 \in (1+3i)$ and that $i+(1+3i) = 3 + (1+ 3i)$ in R. I am unsure how to find the elements of this factor ring?

I know how to find the elements of, for example $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^{2}+1)$, but unsure about this example with Gaussian integers.

Comment: So in the factor ring, $1 + 3i = 0$, or $1 = -3i$, or $i = 3$.

Comment: Note that $i-3=i(1+3i)$ and hence, by definition, your first statement. This implies that $[i-3]=[0]$ in $R$ and hence that $[i]=[3]$, which is your second statement.

Comment: $(1+3i)$ and $(3-i)$ generate the same ideal, so this is an exact duplicate.